# Hide ImageView above screen/programmatically set y position negative

Tags: java, android, imageview, position

I've hid an Imageview with a negative marginTop in the xml. And this view slides into the screen from it's negative position on start.

But when i try to hide it programmatically, it can only be set to y position 0.

I've tried to set the margin to a negative number like this

```
ImageView tip = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tipscreen);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tip.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, 0-350, 0, 0);
tip.setLayoutParams(params);

//and i've also tried
tip.setY(-350);
```

Nothing works, it just sets the position to 0.

So my questions is how the fudge do i set y position of the imageview to -350?

Comment: Do you need to? Do you just want it to disappear or slide off the screen, or?

Comment: Yeah i need it to be outside the screen so that it can slide in later on. I solved it now and will post the answer.

Comment: Ok, well you should look into View Animations ( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html ) even though you got it fixed, it can be really helpful for sliding in and out, scaling, etc

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to deal with negative numbers.  If you are trying to cause a view to slide in, then you can position it where you would like for it to be and use an animation.  Sliding in from the top is not a default animation, but you can write your own.

Then you can use the `View.setVisible(View.VISIBLE)` and `View.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE)` with this animation to get the desired affect.  The animation that you should be looking into would be one related to a `TranslateAnimation`.  Animating views can be referenced at the [Animating Layout Changes URL](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html) for further information.

Comment: it's not really an animation, it depends on a touch event and changes position via a countDownTimer. But thanks for the help but i solved it

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

Turns out that if you put a negative number in the setY() method it'll subtract that from its current position. So i simply changed it to

```
tip.setY(0-350);
```

I'm crying and laughing right now, hopefully someone else might find this useful in the future! :')

Comment: That still puts a negative number in the `setY()` method.  The mathematical equation gets evaluated first and then the method is called.   Was there something else that you changed worth sharing?

Comment: That was the only change. It's just that if i didn't put the 0 in there it would just subtract 350 from whatever y position the view was currently at, but i wanted it to be -350 from the absolute top (0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use android.view.View.setTop(int top) instead of setting margins.

Comment: I tried that but when it animates into screen again it got all buggy and the image was half and pixels were all over the place, really weird :s